# VXWORKS simulator limits?

Tags: c++, file-io, vxworks

I am currently working on porting a code under VxWorks. so I use the simulator to validate changes.
This code requires the opening of many pipes and sockets. I have a problem with the opening of these files descriptors. Indeed, I can open 17 files descriptors (sockets or pipes cause the same error) but the following return the error "EMFILE: too many opened files".
After some research on the net, I modified the global variable NUM_FILES, but this change had no effect.
Do you know if this is the simulator that limits the number of files descriptors opened simultaneously ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem

i had to modify RTP_FD_NUM_MAX
it was a specific RTP value

Answer (score 2):

I also had problems with not enough file descriptors being available. Setting `NUM_FILES` to 50 or so solved the problem. The limitation is within the VxWorks kernel which statically allocated the file descriptor table.

As far as I know changing `NUM_FILES` requires the kernel to be recompiled since it is a kernel configuration value.

You can count the number of free file descriptors by compiling and executing the following function on the VxWorks shell:

```
int countFreeFds(void)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    FILE *fd[100];

    for (count = 0; count < 100; count++)
    {
        fd[count] = fopen("somefile", "r");   /* some any existing file */
        if (fd[count] == NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i = (count - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        fclose(fd[i]);
    }

    return (count);
}
```

If you do that on a freshly started VxWorks with no further binary loaded or tasks being started the value returned by `countFreeFds` will return a number close to `NUM_FILES`.

(also note that I've not tested the function above since right now I haven't got access to the source I've used some years ago ... you may also want to modify the code to use sockets or pipes instead but concerning free file descriptors it makes no difference)

Comment: Yes, after modified the value I'd recompiled the kernel
I'm sure that the value NUM_FILES has been modified because I print it during init of VxWorks and it's equal to 100 like I modified it in the kernel.

Comment: I'm working in a RTP, I don't know  if it could affect the problem.